# Do you need to purchase the "Rezurrection" map pack to get the new Mule Kick perk?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Has the new "Mule Kick" perk, introduced with one of the new map packs, been added to all of the map? If so, do you need to get the new map pack to get the new perk?

Comment: Which game is this about?

Comment: Call of Duty sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Call of Duty wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mule_Kick):

> - In the update that took place on September 27th, Mule Kick is now available on all Maps for Xbox 360 and PS3. PC update is unknown at this time.
> - It's not necessary to have the Rezurrection Map Pack to have the Mule Kick in Kino Der Toten, "Five" or maps from the other map packs.